# TemplateSyntaxError django link

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.11 and python 3.

I but a link in the page when i click it i get this error.

[image]

any idea?

Comment: You forgot to load `static` tag `{% load static %}`

Comment: You should paste it on the top of every template. Before `{% extends 'base.html %} too

Comment: yes i forget it thank u so mach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to load `static` tag `{% load static %}`